# How to modify field properties in content type using PnP PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to change validation for one column from **optional** to **required** in a specific content type only, using PnP PowerShell.

I have found **Set-PnPField** command but not sure how to use this to update properties in a specific content type only. Following is the code that I have written so far:

```
$FieldName = "<Internal Name of the Field>"
$ListName = "<Name of the List>"
            
# connect to the portal using client id and client secret key
Connect-PnPOnline -Url <SharePoint Site Collecton URL> -ClientId <Client ID> -ClientSecret <Client Secret Key>

# get the current web
$spWeb = Get-PnPWeb -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if($spWeb -ne $null)
{
    #Get the Field from List
    $Field = Get-PnPField -List $ListName -Identity $FieldName -ErrorAction Stop
    #Set the Field Required
    $Field.Required = $True
    $Field.Update()
    $Field.Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

This code is updating the validation for field only at list level. Kindly help me if there is any way to meet the requirement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below one is working for me - It updates in content type:

```
# Get Context
$clientContext = Get-PnPContext
 
# Give target content type name over here
$targetContentType = Get-PnPContentType -Identity "ContentTypeName"
 
# Load target content type and content type fields
$clientContext.Load($targetContentType)
$clientContext.Load($targetContentType.Fields)
 
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
 
# Get required field from the target content type
# Mention field internal name or display name over here
$targetField = $targetContentType.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("TestColumnName")
 
$clientContext.Load($targetField)
 
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
 
# Make content type field required
$targetContentType.FieldLinks.GetById($targetField.Id).Required = 1
 
# Update(UpdateChildren – bool), this value indicates whether the children content type(inheriting from this Content Type) needs to be updated. 0 = False, 1 = True
$targetContentType.Update(0)
 
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
 
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```